# Angular invalid configuration of main route (empty path)

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

In my router configuration I have a `DashboardComponent` configured under the path `'dashboard'` and I'd like to automatically redirect the user to this route when no path is specified (empty path, so just `/`).

This is my code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  /* other routes... */
];
```

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '{path:
>   "", redirectTo: "dashboard"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default
>   value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use
>   'full'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was the lack of the `pathMatch` property of the empty route, which defaults to `prefix`.

However in this case the **`pathMatch`** value should be set to **`full`**:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  /* other routes... */
];
```

The reason is the following:

> Technically, pathMatch = 'full' results in a route hit when the
>   remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match ''. In this example,
>   the redirect is in a top level route so the remaining URL and the
>   entire URL are the same thing.
>
> The other possible pathMatch value is 'prefix' which tells the router
>   to match the redirect route when the remaining URL begins with the
>   redirect route's prefix path.
>
> Don't do that here. If the pathMatch value were 'prefix', every URL
>   would match ''.

For more details refer to the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru Stackoverflow allows me to accept my own answers only after 2 days